# Redux Form field does not hide my passwords

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have trouble trying to hide my password and my confirm password characters.

Does redux form require the name="password" strictly or can I call name="password1".

The Field only seems to hide my password characters when I type name="password", even when type="password" already.

```html
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this))}>
      <div>
          <Field
              label="Username"
              name="username"
              component={this.renderField}
              type="text"
          />
      </div>
      <div>
          <Field
              label="Email"
              name="email"
              component={this.renderField}
              type="text"
          />
      </div>
      <div>
          <Field
              label="First Name"
              name="first_name"
              component={this.renderField}
              type="text"
          />
      </div>
      <div>
          <Field
              label="Last Name"
              name="last_name"
              component={this.renderField}
              type="text"
          />
      </div>
      <div>
          <Field
              label="Password"
              name="password1"
              component={this.renderField}
              type="password"
          />
      </div>
      <div>
          <Field
              label="Confirm Password"
              name="password2"
              component={this.renderField}
              type="password"
          />
      </div>
      {this.renderAlert()}
      <div className="signin-button">
          <button action="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Sign up!</button>
      </div>
      <div className="g-signin2" id="my-signin2" data-width="200"/>
      <Link to="/signin">Already an user?</Link>
  </form>
```

Comment: What's the implementation of `this.renderField`? Based on your description, it wouldn't surprise me if it's not correctly passing down the `type` prop.

Comment: thanks, you're right